# Durandal - Distinguishing entry from a 'back' button vs. navigate()

Tags: durandal

In my Durandal app, I have a search page - I'd like to:

- Load a clean search page when it's loaded from the menu (`router.navigate('#/search')`)
- When navigating to an item from the search page, then using the back button, this should return to the original search result & criteria.

I'm also storing my search criteria & results as a (app-wide) singleton, which is injected to the view model via RequireJS.

**Am I able to:** distinguish how the user entered the page? I can see that the activate() lifecycle call is triggered under both entry methods.

Comment: Yes, what is not working currently when you do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if the user landed to the search page by clicking a link/button from your app or by visiting by entering a url/back button, what I would do is to raise an event when the user clicks on the link/button and on the search page check if the event has been raised or pass some parameter in router.navigate.

Answer (score 1):

I have been recently doing some work on distinguishing a user click from within the application and a back or forward button from the browser. If you are using router.navigate() to navigate around the Durandal application the router.explicitNavigation flag is set to true. But you would want to capture this before the 'router:navigation:complete' event in 'router:route:activating' event as the flag gets set back to false on 'router:navigation:complete' event.

Bottom line is if you are using router.navigate to navigate around the application the router.explicitNavigation property will be set to true and  if navigation is triggered using the back/forward button in the browser router.explicitNavigation will be set to false.

In actual case you might not even need to perform router.navigate() to distinguish between an in app navigation and a browser back/forward because Durandal's router module listens to all 'a' tag click on the document level and sets the explicitNavigation flag to true. However I haven't tested this fully.